# nginx reload - effectively memory leak

Tags: nginx, memory-leaks

When running `nginx -s reload`, nginx is meant to soft reload (gradually close existing connections on the Old process, and service new requests on the New process).

It does that, except it seems that (perhaps) an active request isn't completing on the old process.
Producing a runaway condition whereby if multiple `reload`s are attempted, the server will eventually run out of ram.

Is there a way (c++ module maybe?) to dump what connections nginx is servicing on a **specific** linux pid?
I'm unsure how I can solve this, unless I can find out precisely what isn't allowing nginx to shut itself down.
*(and I can't just turn sites off to divide/conquer, it's a live client server with 200+ websites)*

[image]

nginx version: nginx/1.24.0

Comment: Run `lsof -p $PID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think nginx divides workers by hosts; it can't know which host it's serving before a worker has already dealt with connecting, TLS, HTTP/2 handshaking, and at that point, the request already "belongs" to a worker process.

You could attach gdb to these processes (`gdb -p {pid}`), look which threads there are and what they are waiting for using `info threads`. Maybe one thread is waiting for some IO to complete? Some read from a pipe, some IPC? Choose that thread (`thread {number}`) and do a backtrace (`bt`). You can print local variables (`print {variable name}`) and select the level in the call stack that you want to work with (`frame {stack frame nr.}`).

Comment: Using a combination of this (extremely helpful thank you!!) and `lsof -p`, and `strace` and `netstat -np --inet` I was able to determine the cause. It was vaultwarden (rust built bitwarden instance on localhost) as well as cloudflared (argo tunnel).  Thank you to everyone here, you guys are awesome.